# How to validate email using Kohana 3.1 ORM

Tags: php, validation, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I'm using Kohana 3.1 framework to do a simple validation using Kohana's `ORM` and `Validation` built in classes. Let's see the code...

In the **model** I have these simple rules:

```
public function rules()
{
  return array(
    'first_name' => array(
      array('not_empty'),
    ),
    'email' => array(
      array('not_empty'),
      array('email'),
    ),
  );
}
```

then in the **controller** I *try to* validate and save the object with the classic `try ... catch` construct:

```
try
{
    $t = array(
        'first_name'=>'pippo',
        'email'=>'foo@foo.com',
    );

    ORM::factory('customer')->values($t)->save();

}
catch ( ORM_Validation_Exception $e )
{
    die(Debug::vars($e->errors('')));
}
```

Now the `$t` array above should validate, but it doesn't. It instead throws an exception and dies calling `Debug::vars` and printing this error:

```
array(1) (
    "email" => string(23) "email must not be empty"
)
```

This is clearly not true, **what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: I was doing it WRONG on the relations side, actually field `email` column was on a foreign related table I haven't linked yet..

Answer (score 1):

So have you sorted it or not?

instead of:

```
$t = array(
  'first_name'=>'pippo',
  'email'=>'foo@foo.com',
);

ORM::factory('customer')->values($t)->save();
```

why don't you try:

```
$customer = ORM::factory('customer');

$customer->first_name = 'pippo';
$customer->email = 'foo@foo.com';

$customer->save();
```

Its a little bit more clean cut and explicit. Then you'd have never had any confusion on whether email was set, so you know to start looking else where.
Just a thought.